# Ability to click through salesforce reports

Tags: salesforce, report

I want to perform the following. I have a report of summary type with four fields say name type date and status. Report is generated based on the filter. When the report is run, it displays the list of records for that report. I want some of the field values in the report to be a hyperlink.i.e., want that to be navigated to the record detail page if i click a particular field value. Please let me know what are the options available. Here is the screenshot attached for reference.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly name fields in salesforce will have hyperlink by default. For other fields if we want to have we need to have custom formula field for the object. I created a custom formula field with the HYPERLINK function.

Here is the formula

```js
HYPERLINK( 
IF( 
CONTAINS($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, 'visual'), 
'https://'+ 
MID($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, FIND( 'visual', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260)-4,4) 
+'salesforce.com/', 
LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, FIND( '/pagename', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260)) 
) + Id , 
custom field name/ or any string 

)
```